# C++ for loop with no conditions

Tags: c++, for-loop

I ran across this
    for ( ; ; ) {}

A quick cursory search lead me nowhere in finding out what this means. It looks like another thread might be handling terminating this. Is this equivalent to 'while (TRUE) {}' ?

Comment: `while(TRUE){}` isn't valid C++. Both `while(true){}` and `for(;;){}` are undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB How exactly are either of those undefined behavior?

Comment: @Kevin http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1528.htm

Comment: @Kevin: 1.10/24: "The implementation may assume that every thread teminates."

Comment: @KerrekSB: That refers to 6.8.5p5, which says: "An iteration statement whose controlling expression is not a constant expression, that
performs no input/output operations, does not access volatile objects, and performs no
  synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling expression, or (in the case of a **for** statement) its *expression-3*, may be assumed by the implementation to
terminate.". That doesn't apply to `for (;;) {}`. (A footnote says that `for (;;)` is treated as having a constant controlling expression.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I don't have a 6.8.5 in my C++... which revision are you referring to?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry, I directed that to the wrong person. BartoszKP cited n1528.htm, which refers to that clause in the C standard. I think you're right about C++. (I dislike the way the C++ standard says "The implementation may assume that any thread ..." rather than something like "If any thread does not ..., the behavior is undefined". I have the same problem with the C standard. But that's somewhat beside the point.)

Comment: @KerrekSB interestingly, the C standard (as Keith quoted) allows no such assumption (as the controlling expression is constant). Does the c++ standard ever explicitly say that demonstrably false assumptions (such as the one in question) cause undefined behavior, or is it just implictly neglected by the standard?

Comment: @Kevin: It says (with more detail) what I quoted. If you violate the assumptions, that's undefined behaviour. I don't think it's neglect, but rather quite deliberate, and I believe some aggressively optimizing compilers (Clang?) will take advantage of that, too.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is there a "standard defined" way to make an infinite loop in C++?

Comment: @becko: You need to have something happen inside the loop, e.g. reading an atomic variable. If you're just messing around and don't have anything to do, you can access a volatile object.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh, it's only `while(true) {}` (with an empty body) that's undefined. If I do something inside the loop, like `while(true) { int i = 2 + 2; }`, it's defined?

Comment: @becko: It has to be something sufficiently non-trivial (see above reference), which includes things like I/O, synchronization and volatile accesses. Just `int i = 2 + 2;` is not enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an infinite loop. Any of the three parts of a `for` loop (initialization, condition and increment) can be missing. Specifically, if the condition in a `for` loop is missing, it is treated as being true. So it is equivalent to `while(1) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are equivalent in functionalities.